# When the image size is large, the GStreamer pipeline using shmsink and shmsrc stops

Tags: linux, camera, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I want to transfer large images through shared memory.
When I send a 4000x3000 pixel image using shmsink and shmsrc in GStreamer, the image stops after a few frames are displayed.
However, it doesn't crash, just the image stops. There are no error messages.

This is the command for send.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \
! "video/x-raw,format=(string)YUY2,width=(int)640,height=(int)480,pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1,framerate=(fraction)30/1" \
! videoscale \
! "video/x-raw, width=(int)4000, height=(int)3000" \
! shmsink socket-path=/tmp/foo
```

And this is command for receive.

```
gst-launch-1.0 shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/foo \
! "video/x-raw,format=(string)YUY2,width=(int)4000,height=(int)3000,pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1,framerate=(fraction)30/1" \
! xvimagesink
```

Here's what we tried.

- Change the image size to 3600x2700 -> works correctly
- Change the shmsink in the send pipeline to xvimagesink -> works correctly

I'm waiting for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved.
I added the option "wait-for-connection=false" to shmsink to prevent it from stopping.

The receive pipeline remains unchanged, but the send pipeline is now as follows.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \
! "video/x-raw,format=(string)YUY2,width=(int)640,height=(int)480,pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1,framerate=(fraction)30/1" \
! videoscale \
! "video/x-raw, width=(int)4000, height=(int)3000" \
! shmsink socket-path=/tmp/foo wait-for-connection=false
```

I didn't get the information from anywhere, I just changed all the options of shmsink and it worked by accident.

I don't know why it worked, so if you can tell me why, I'd appreciate it.